# What is the difference between numpy array with dimension of size 1 and without that dimension

Tags: python, numpy

I'm might be a bit confused. But I wonder what is the difference between say x[2,3] and y[2,3,1] (same array but have extra dimension with size 1).

Are they the same or there is difference between them.

Comment: Let's say `a = [1, 2, 3]` `a`'s shape is `(3, )`. `b = [[1], [2], [3]]` now`b`'s shape is `(3, 1)`.

Comment: Thanks .. so what is the difference in this case between (3, ) and (3)?

Comment: `(3)` is just `3` while `(3, )` is a tuple of size 1.

Comment: The `shape` is reported as a `tuple`. In python , `()`, `(3,)`, and `(3,2)` are tuples.  `(3)` is not.  It's hard to use `numpy` without a basic knowledge of python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a 2D example

```
# shape (2,)
a = np.array([0,1])
# shape (2,1)
b = np.array([[3],[4]])
```

You can consider `a` to be a single row with 2 columns (actually a 1D vector), and `b` array to be 2 rows with one column.

Let's try to add them:

```
a+a
# addition on a single dimension
# array([0, 2])

b+b
# also common dimensions
# array([[6],
#        [8]])

a+b
# different dimensions with one of common size
# addition will be broadcasted to generate a (2,2) shape
# array([[3, 5],
#        [4, 6]])
```